# print result after submitting in laravel

Tags: laravel, forms

how can I create a submit button that can show the pdf result of my form to print it directly?
this is my code below

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('dashboard/generate') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-ui">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Distributor</label>
                    <select name="distributor" id="type" class="form-control">
                      <option value="">Choose Distributor</option>
                      @foreach ($distributor as $item)
                      <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
                      @endforeach
                    </select>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Select Event</label>
                    <select name="event" id="type" class="form-control">
                      <option value="">Choose Event</option>
                      @foreach ($event as $item)
                      <option value="{{ $item->id }}">({{ $item->events->date }}, {{ $item->time }}, {{ $item->events->stage }})-{{ $item->title }}</option>
                      @endforeach
                    </select>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">SUBMIT</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    window.print();
  } 
</script>
```

but it just print the current page (the form page). any advice i can try?

Comment: maybe you can try this out https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf. You need something that when you submit your input to build a .pdf out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this onsubmit jquery event**

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 10px;">
 <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</div>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').on('submit', '.formsubmit', function(e) {
   alert(1);
 });
```

Comment: please give upvote this answer if its help for you Thank you so much @Farah Aidina